# In Symfony2, how can I generate a PHP file dynamically and use it in the service container?

Tags: symfony

## What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to create a PHP file on a container pass, and then register the file with the service container.

## Why I'm trying to do it

In Symfony2, I want to offer dynamic forms that end users can control - including validation and templating (think Wufoo). The approach I'm using (which is working) is to store the configuration in the database in YAML, parse the YAML file and loop through it to add the fields. This bit is working.

I've cached the rendering of the form, so that's quick, but it's slow when somebody submits the form because it loads the configuration, parses the YAML, loops through to build the form, etc on every page load.

What I'd like to do instead is generate the `Type` file on a compiler pass, then register the resulting file with the service container, tagged as a form. I guess something like this is possible, since Twig does something similar. However, I can't figure out how it does it.

## What I've tried

I'm able to dynamically generate the PHP file itself, but I don't know where to store it or how to register it.

Comment: You can generate class with specific namespace and then register that class in DIC. When your code will try to load that class, autoloader will handle everything automatically.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing but don't know where to start. Would you be kind enough to offer pointers?